# Batch size not passed to tf.keras model: "Error when checking input: expected input1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (a,b)"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tfrecord, tf.data.dataset

I'm new to tensorflow (v 2.4.1), so this may be very trivial, but I cannot figure it out on my own. I'm passing 2-dimensional (30,1024) tensors to my 2-input **tf.keras** model through tf.data.Dataset. After batching, the dataset is printed as

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ({sentence1: (None, 30, 1024), sentence2: (None, 30, 1024)}, (None, 1)), types: ({sentence1: tf.float32, sentence2: tf.float32}, tf.int64)>
```

The relevant part of the model is:

```
shared_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                layers.Masking(),
                layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()])

input_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(30,1024), dtype=tf.float32, name='sentence1')
input_2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(30,1024), dtype=tf.float32, name='sentence2')

encoder1 = shared_model(input_1)
encoder2 = shared_model(input_2)
...
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_1,input_2], outputs=final_layer)
```

However, when I call model.fit(), I get the error warning "Error when checking input: expected sentence1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1024)". That is, the batch size is not passed to the model.

I tried reshaping my tensors to (1,30,1024). The dataset then becomes

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ({sentence1: (None, 1, 30, 1024), sentence2: (None, 1, 30, 1024)}, (None, 1)), types: ({sentence1: tf.float32, sentence2: tf.float32}, tf.int64)>
```

However, now I get the error "Error when checking input: expected sentence1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 1, 30, 1024)". So now the batch size suddenly **is** passed to the model. Any idea why this happens? Thanks a million.

EDIT: I think the problem is due to the way the dataset is generated in the first place. I obtained it from a TFRecord file by means of these helper functions:

```
def load_dataset(filename):
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([filename])
    dataset = raw_dataset.map(prepare_dataset_for_training)
    return dataset

def prepare_dataset_for_training(example):
    context_features = {
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)}
    sequence_features = {
        'embeddings1': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'embeddings2': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32)}
    parsed_context, parsed_feature_lists = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(
        example,
        context_features=context_features,
        sequence_features=sequence_features)
    emb1 = tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse(parsed_feature_lists['embeddings1'])
    emb1 = tf.reshape(emb1.to_tensor(), shape=(30,1024))
    emb2 = tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse(parsed_feature_lists['embeddings2'])
    emb2 = tf.reshape(emb2.to_tensor(), shape=(30,1024))
    label = tf.expand_dims(parsed_context['label'], axis=0)
    return ({'sentence1': emb1, 'sentence2': emb2}, label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what could be the problem because I couldn't reproduce it. Perhaps you made a typo on your model.fit call that said to train on a 2D input rather than a 3D one?

Here's the code I ran to reproduce my results:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy.random as npr
import tensorflow as tf

shared_model = keras.Sequential([
                layers.Masking(),
                layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()])

input_1 = keras.Input(shape=(30,1024), dtype=tf.float32, name='sentence1')
input_2 = keras.Input(shape=(30,1024), dtype=tf.float32, name='sentence2')
x = tf.concat((input_1, input_2), axis=1)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(8)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1,input_2], outputs=x)

m = 40
BATCH_SIZE = 4
inp_1 = npr.randn(m, 30, 1024)
inp_2 = npr.randn(m, 30, 1024)
y = npr.uniform(size=(m, 8))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'sentence1': inp_1, 'sentence2': inp_2}, y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE) # shape is (None, 30, 1024), (None, 30, 1024)
model.compile('adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(dataset, epochs=100)
pred = model.predict([inp_1, inp_2])[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful comment. Thanks to your feedback, I now think the issue may actually be more complicated than I thought at the beginning, as my dataset has been obtained from a TFRecord file by means of a tf.data.TFRecordDataset. There must be some clash with the batching. I add the details to the question in an edit.